# Can I fetch the tweet from Twitter if I know the tweet's id?

Tags: twitter

Can I fetch the tweet from Twitter if I know the tweet's id?

Comment: If you're programming for twitter, you could just look through the API docs and easily find the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for tweets with t.co rewritten links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561016/search-for-tweets-with-t-co-rewritten-links)

Answer (score 102):

@Adjam & @Gibron

You can use any user name and the url will redirect to the correct twitter handle.

For instance, if I go to:

```
twitter.com/anyuser/status/541278904204668929
```

The link redirects to:

```
https://twitter.com/MarkTabNet/status/541278904204668929
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Wonder where did you get this.

Comment: @Jim Can you provide an example tweet id that doesn't work, as well as it's url (if you happen to know it)? I'm assuming it's a public tweet and not a dm.

Comment: @datalifenyc Thanks for providing with the link. I was wondering if only given a user id, that is to say I don't know the user's name, how to deal with that?

Comment: Apparently this is not working anymore, at least in some cases

Comment: @Kr1 Can you provide me with an example of a tweet that does not work? I will take a look.

Comment: @datalifenyc, actually it works well. The problem was related to JavaScript, I was not getting the whole ID as explained there: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ids

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to use the API or know the user account.

Just drop it into the following URL format, where XXXXXXXXX is the tweet id.

https://twitter.com/i/web/status/XXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. Check out [Twitter's API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/:id)

Comment: Page moved again; please see @Syed's answer as of 7/19/11.

Answer (score 4):

yes we can fetch by https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid , if will fetch the status of the single id..

Answer (score 3):

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/id.json

Example: 
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/130022282960715776.json

Comment: They've updated their api and this no longer works T.T

Comment: This worked for me:  https://twitter.com/Tweet_Maker_User_Name/status/447788271175999488

Comment: Adjam that requires <Tweet_Maker_User_Name> which is not always available and not part of the parameters of the question.

Comment: not Working https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=98030675097174016 says: {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]} but no example in the f*** twitter api for how you put the key into the url

Answer (score 1):

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=50?q=from:{twittername}

Comment: v1 API's are no longer active, v1.1 must be used.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the [public API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses%C2%A0show).

Answer (score 0):

we could test twitter api in https://apigee.com/console/twitter

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/335393046625652736.json
```

Comment: Unfortunately Apigee has deprecated their API console's so this answer is no longer valid: https://apigee.com/about/blog/api-technology/were-sunsetting-classic-api-consoles