# Search for tweets with t.co rewritten links

Tags: twitter

Just noticed a spike of visitors following a t.co/LINKHERE a link re-written by twitter. Is there a way to track back to the twitter message that contained the link, if you know the link?

Comment: Do you mean to do this programmatically, or do you just want to do a search on search.twitter.com? As far as I know, it's not possible to get the referring tweet's id from the t.co link (unless you are Twitter). Your best bet would be to 1) check out https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities for api search or 2) search for the un-shortened URL, as I don not believe the t.co links "show up" in search.

Comment: No they don't. I think if a string is matched as a URL it is replaced with a shortener ID and even though it appears in the actually results the search does not pick up the ID. If it makes any sense. I actually found some post by Twitter about issues with API due to URL shortener usage. I was just hoping to find tweet that contained the URL to my site.

Comment: I feel for your plight, Twitter makes it exceedingly difficult to find the source of things. In the future, it might be easiest to share each link with some sort of unique identifier of your own. For example, www.domain.com/page-1?ref=XYZ

Comment: Twitter automatically replaced any links in messages with short URLs, that start with t.co/...

Comment: I mean WHAT is the particular t.co LINK you're referring to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using twitter API 1.1. The easiest way is to use the api is through the twitter API console. Here are the steps:

1. Goto https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console
2. Select `https://api.twitter.com/1.1` from the `Service` dropdown menu.
3. Select `OAuth 1` from the `Authentication` dropdown menu and authorize with your twitter account.
4. Choose `GET` `/search/tweets.json` api.
5. Type the t.co link (e.g. `https://t.co/w6iqrcuZMA`) in `q` query parameter (**Try both http and https links**. In my case the http link returned no record while https link returned some records). All the search results will be returned in json format.
6. Now to open the actual tweet use this link (fill the placeholders of course): `https://twitter.com/{user.screen_name}/status/{id_str}`

Comment: Looks like the REST console is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

The standard twitter search will work for a few days.

For older t.co links, you could try searching with
[find-tco.appspot.com](http://find-tco.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Here’s the quick and easy way:

1. Go to: http://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console
2. Service: “api.twitter.com/1.1”
3. Authentication: OAuth 1, then log in if you need to
4. Make sure GET is selected and paste `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=http%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2F{**SUFFIX**}` into the Request URL box.
5. Replace `**SUFFIX**` with the t.co URL suffix. So if the URL you’re searching for is `t.co/**N2ul8FFCxu**`, the link you pasted should look like this:

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=http%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2F{**N2ul8FFCxu**}`

6. Click Send
7. Open a new tab and paste `twitter.com/**SCREEN_NAME**/status/**ID_STR**` into the address bar
8. Replace `**SCREEN_NAME**` and `**ID_STR**` with info from Response. Like this:

`twitter.com/**twitter**/status/**526534593826938881**`

Answer (score 0):

t.co links do show up in search, so if you're curious, you have about a week to find them before they get dropped from the search index.

For example:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=https:%2F%2Ft.co%2FGJMsIcM6

Returns:

```
{
  "completed_in": 0.019,
  "max_id": 178215431251828740,
  "max_id_str": "178215431251828736",
  "page": 1,
  "query": "https%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2FGJMsIcM6",
  "refresh_url": "?since_id=178215431251828736&q=https%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2FGJMsIcM6",
  "results": [
    {
      "created_at": "Fri, 09 Mar 2012 20:27:24 +0000",
      "from_user": "kurrik",
      "from_user_id": 7588892,
      "from_user_id_str": "7588892",
      "from_user_name": "Arne Roomann-Kurrik",
      "geo": null,
      "id": 178215431251828740,
      "id_str": "178215431251828736",
      "iso_language_code": "en",
      "metadata": {
        "result_type": "recent"
      },
      "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/24229162/arne001_normal.jpg",
      "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/24229162/arne001_normal.jpg",
      "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/tweetbutton&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Tweet Button&lt;/a&gt;",
      "text": "RT @raffi: “Twitter Catches the 'SPDY' Train” from @wired → http://t.co/suCbWWEl (&amp; they reference my tweet! → https://t.co/GJMsIcM6)",
      "to_user": null,
      "to_user_id": null,
      "to_user_id_str": null,
      "to_user_name": null
    },
    {
      "created_at": "Fri, 09 Mar 2012 20:26:26 +0000",
      "from_user": "raffi",
      "from_user_id": 8285392,
      "from_user_id_str": "8285392",
      "from_user_name": "Raffi Krikorian",
      "geo": null,
      "id": 178215186921033730,
      "id_str": "178215186921033730",
      "iso_language_code": "en",
      "metadata": {
        "result_type": "recent"
      },
      "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1270234259/raffi-headshot-casual_normal.png",
      "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1270234259/raffi-headshot-casual_normal.png",
      "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/tweetbutton&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Tweet Button&lt;/a&gt;",
      "text": "“Twitter Catches the 'SPDY' Train” from @wired → http://t.co/suCbWWEl (&amp; they reference my tweet! → https://t.co/GJMsIcM6)",
      "to_user": null,
      "to_user_id": null,
      "to_user_id_str": null,
      "to_user_name": null
    }
  ],
  "results_per_page": 15,
  "since_id": 0,
  "since_id_str": "0"
}
```

You'll see that search returns retweets as well.

Comment: {
errors: [
{
message: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.",
code: 68
}
]
}

Comment: Yeah, the API endpoint mentioned is now expired.  You'll need to use http://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=https:%2F%2Ft.co%2FGJMsIcM6 instead, which unfortunately won't work in a browser.  Try using the OAuth tool on the right hand side of https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets to generate a valid request.